# After successful "merge" on Git. I still got weird file

Tags: git

this file is weird. See there are "<<<<<>>>>>" in my file .
How can I make it right??

Thank you!

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.18'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
<<<<<<< HEAD
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'pg'
=======
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end
>>>>>>> sign-up
```

Actually ,I have doen merge successfully.

see:

andy@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/app2012$ git me
    rge sign-up

Already up-to-date.

Edited:

When I do git status, I got this:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'heroku/master' by 2 commits.
#
```

Comment: The merge was *not* performed successfully. You have a merge conflict, but you told Git that it had been resolved. See for example the section [Basic Merge Conflicts](http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html) in http://progit.org.

Comment: That right there is called a conflict, which means that you didn't merge successfully. You don't use `git merge` to see what your status is, try `git status`, I'm betting it'll show you that this file is conflicted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't have a successful merge, you had a merge with conflicts.  Both sides of the merge touched the same code, and git presented it for you to figure out what it should look like.

What you did instead is to commit the bits that show where the conflict was; your best bet is to `git reset --hard` to the branch before the merge, and then redo it - but actually fix the conflict this time.

http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html has a section on merge conflicts that should help you out understanding exactly what happened and what to do about it.

Comment: Also, even if you have a "successful" merge without conflicts, that's no guarantee that your code will work. You should still verify that before committing.